# OrmLite-named in memory database throwing exception

Tags: sqlite, servicestack, 32-bit, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to use in memory database for unit test. following is set up for resolving apphost dependency of database

```
               OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqliteDialect.Provider;
                 var dbFactory =  new OrmLiteConnectionFactory();
                dbFactory.RegisterConnection("keyname",":memory:",SqliteDialect.Provider);
                container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);
```

I am using sqlite(32 bit version) for 32bit machine. My project build target platform is "Any CPU". I am getting following error

```
An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqliteNET.dll but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider' threw an exception.
```

am I missing some setting or anything?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows. Sqlite 32 bit is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the deprecated version of [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32/) which was discontinued last year. Since you have a 32bit machine I'd recommend instead using:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono/

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono
```

Which has the benefit of also working on Mono in both OSX/Linux.

Comment: Thanks mythz for reply